# navigate to a particular part of a scrolllview

Tags: android, scrollview, navigateuri

I have an horizontal scrollview composed of 3 linear layouts (3pages).
How can I navigate to the 3rd layout of my scrollview? (by default, it navigates on the 1st layout of the page)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29).

Sadly I can't post any example code right now since I'm on my phone, but I think you'll find enough tutorials for it online.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work! I call the function "scrollto" or "scrollby", none of them work!